# Open Utilty Bar On the Onload (connectedCallback) functtion LWC Component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, utility-bar

I have LWC Component and I need to open the utility page on the connectedCallback of the page:
Somewhat like this:
https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/open-utility-bar-on-lightning-app-load/

However, I am not sure how to use component.find there?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Spring '19](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_console_lwc_utility.htm&type=5&release=218) ...

> Bring modern, blazing-fast Lightning web components (LWC) into the utility bar by adding the `lightning__UtilityBar` target to your LWC‘s meta configuration. **LWC utilities don’t yet support APIs or being used as background utility items.**

However... You **might** be able to go for a hybrid solution where you use an Aura Component in your utility bar that includes your LWC component and communicate with it (I haven't tried it myself)

This way, your Aura component would act as a proxy and fire / listen to the events you need from that api